# Getting data from dataframe to MS-access DB Target Tables using R

Tags: r, ms-access

I have created Data frames in R. I have connected to access DB using below code.
I am able to extract all data from access db to R.

I have 3 tables in Access like A , B , C

Created same data frames in R like A, B, C

How to move the R data frames of A, B, C from R to Access DB Target Tables A,B,C?

Using R coding in R studio.?

Please help on this, this is important task for me.

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                          DBQ=C:/Users/chintan/Desktop/Published.accdb")

# Get data
Pub <- sqlQuery(con, "select * from certifications
                      Where [Business Group]='EG'
                      AND FY='FY15'")
```

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at the [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) manual. There are multiple ways to append data frames to Access tables. Of course be sure data frame columns align to table columns by name and data type.

**sqlUpdate** *(Write or update a table in an ODBC database)*

```
sqlSave(con, pub, AccessTablename, append = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)

sqlUpdate(con, pub, Accesstablename)
```

**sqlQuery** *(Submit an SQL query to an ODBC database, and retrieve the results)*

```
# APPEND QUERY
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO AccessTableName(col1, col2, col3) 
               VALUES('", pub$col1 ,"','", pub$col2, "','",pub$col3, "')")

appendRecords <- lapply(sql, function(x) sqlQuery(con, x))


# UPDATE QUERY
sql <- paste0("UPDATE AccessTableName 
                  SET col1 = '", pub$col1 ,"'
                      col2 = '", pub$col2 ,"'
                      col3 = '", pub$col3 ,"'")

appendRecords <- lapply(sql, function(x) sqlQuery(con, x))
```

---

You can even mirror VBA using [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) and export data frames to csv by opening an Access application object (with DoCmd property) and run the [DoCmd.TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) method.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

# OUTPUT R DATA FRAME TO CSV
rdfpath = 'C:\\Path\\To\\R\\DataFrame\\Output.csv'
write.csv(pub, rdfpath, row.names=FALSE)

# LAUNCH ACCESS APP
strDbName = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb'
oApp = COMCreate("Access.Application")
oApp$OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)

# IMPORT CSV DATA TO TABLE
acImportDelim  <- 0
importObj = oApp[["DoCmd"]]
importObj$TransferText(acImportDelim, "", "AccessTableName", rdfpath, TRUE)

importObj$CloseDatabase
importObj <- NULL
oApp <- NULL
```

Comment: I have used the below code its is missing some records i have 8000 records but only 7800 got inserted to db. any reason for that 

# APPEND QUERY
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO AccessTableName(col1, col2, col3) 
               VALUES('", pub$col1 ,"','", pub$col2, "','",pub$col3, "')")

appendRecords <- lapply(sql, function(x) sqlQuery(con, x)

Comment: Check the data types of R compared to data types in Access table. Access silently ignores such mismatches without raising errors.

Comment: Looks like this is due to Special character in the string eg:('\\\\.\\ROOT\\CIMV2' \\n  \\n...''." ).