# Export R data frame to MS Access

Tags: r

I am trying to export a data frame from R to MS Access but it seems to me that there is no package available to do this task. Is there a way to export a data frame directly to Access? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't look like related to programming directly, so please consider using another site for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting data from dataframe to MS-access DB Target Tables using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001509/getting-data-from-dataframe-to-ms-access-db-target-tables-using-r)

Answer (score 4):

The following works for medium sized datasets, but may fail if MyRdataFrame is too large for the 2GB limit of Access or conversion type errors.

```
 library(RODBC)

 db <- "C:Documents/PreviouslySavedBlank.accdb"

 Mycon <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)

 sqlSave(Mycon, MyRdataFrame)
```

Comment: this did not work for me because 1) my file path was too long, so I had to create a db connection first and 2) sqlSave gives an error that Argument 1 must have names

Answer (score 0):

There is the [ImportExport](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ImportExport) package.

**The database has to already exist** (at least in my case). So you have to create it first.
It has to be a access database 2000 version with extension **.mdb**

Here is an example:

```
ImportExport::access_export("existing_databse.mdb",as.data.frame(your_R_data),
                            tablename="bob")
```

with "bob" the name of the table you want to create in the database. Choose your own name of course and it has to be a non already existing table

It will also add a first column called *rownames* which is just an index column

Note that creating a .accdb file and then changing the extension to .mdb wont work ^^ you really have to open it and save it as .mdb. I added as.data.frame() but if your data is already one then no need.

There might be a way for .**accdb** files using directly **sqlSave** (which is used internally by ImportExport) and specifying the driver from the RODBC package. This is in the link in the comment from @BenJacobson. But the solution above worked for me and it was only one line.